# std::thread taking lambda with ref arg fails to compile

Tags: c++, generics, lambda, c++14

I'm reading [C++ concurrency in action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988770). Chapter 2.4 describes a parallell_accumulate algorithm.

I tried - as a learning experiment - to replace the functor used there, with a generic lambda.

I've distilled the compilation error down to:

```
#include <thread>

template <typename T>
struct f {
    void operator() (T& result) { result = 1;}
};

int main() {
    int x = 0;
    auto g = [](auto& result) { result = 1; };

    std::thread(f<int>(), std::ref(x));  // COMPILES
    std::thread(g, std::ref(x));         // FAILS TO COMPILE
}
```

The error message:

```
 In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/thread:39:0,
                 from foo.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/functional: In instantiation of ‘struct std::_Bind_simple<main()::<lambda(auto:1&)>(std::reference_wrapper<int>)>’:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/thread:140:47:   required from ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = main()::<lambda(auto:1&)>&; _Args = {std::reference_wrapper<int>}]’
foo.cpp:13:31:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.9/functional:1665:61: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<main()::<lambda(auto:1&)>(std::reference_wrapper<int>)>’
       typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;
                                                             ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/functional:1695:9: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<main()::<lambda(auto:1&)>(std::reference_wrapper<int>)>’
         _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Indices...>)
         ^
```

My compiler version

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 4.9.1-16ubuntu6) 4.9.1
```

Why do the compilation fail for the lambda but not the functor?

**EDIT:** How can I achieve what the functor is doing (assigning to a ref) with a generic lambda?

Comment: `f` isn't exactly equivalent to the generic lambda. Having a template `operator()()` would be more precise (and it will produce the same error).

Comment: `std::bind` is specified to unwrap `reference_wrapper` arguments before passing them to the target function, so [`std::thread(std::bind(g, std::ref(x)))` works as you intend](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f908c16c78c4027).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Another variation on the same theme that template argument deduction doesn't look through conversions.

The `operator()` of `f<int>` is

```
void operator() (int& result);
```

when you pass a `reference_wrapper<int>` to it, the conversion function (`operator int &`) is called, yielding a reference that can be bound to `result`.

The `operator()` of your generic lambda is

```
template<class T> void operator() (T& result) const;
```

If it were passed a `reference_wrapper` lvalue, it would deduce `T` as a `reference_wrapper` and then fail to compile on the assignment. (Assignment to a `reference_wrapper` reseats the "reference" rather than affects the value.)

But it fails even before that, because the standard requires that what you pass to `std::thread` must be callable with prvalues - and a non-const lvalue reference doesn't bind to a prvalue. This is the error you see - `result_of` contains no `type` because your functor is not callable for the argument type. If you attempt to do `g(std::ref(x));`, clang [produces](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ca2ae4adb8f4c12c) a rather clear error:

```
main.cpp:16:5: error: no matching function for call to object of type '(lambda at main.cpp:11:14)'
    g(std::ref(x));
    ^
main.cpp:11:14: note: candidate function [with $auto-0-0 = std::__1::reference_wrapper<int>] not viable: expects an l-value for 1st argument
    auto g = [](auto& result) { result = 1; };         
    ^
```

---

You should probably consider just capturing the relevant local by reference:

```
auto g = [&x]() { x = 1; };
```

Or if, for whatever reason, you must use a generic lambda, then you might take a `reference_wrapper` by value (or by const reference), and then unwrap it using `get()`:

```
 auto g = [](auto result) { result.get() = 1; };
```

or perhaps add a `std::bind` which will unwrap the `reference_wrapper`s, which lets template argument deduction do the right thing (hat tip @Casey):

```
 std::thread(std::bind(g, std::ref(x)));
```

or perhaps dispense with this `reference_wrapper` nonsense and write your lambda to take a non-owning pointer instead:

```
auto g = [](auto* result) { *result = 1; };
std::thread(g, &x);
```

Comment: Wow! Sometimes clang is awesome. That's the reason why you should check suspicious code snippets with multiple compilers.

Comment: @Drop Well, to be fair, it's awesome when you reduced it to a plain function call `g(std::ref(x));`; it's not really awesome on the original code in the OP.

Comment: I love you @T.C. -- Only took over 5 stackoverflow links to find my answer. (`std::thread(g, &x);`)

Answer (score 5):

There are all sorts of problems involved with passing arguments through the "INVOKE(...)" family of functions [`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async), [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind), [`std::thread::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread). If you want to use an overloaded function name, or pass an lvalue reference, or heaven forbid pass an rvalue by reference, you're going to have a hard time. You'll come here to SO and one of us who has learned the relevant incantation will pass it on to you. Hopefully you'll remember it the next time it comes up.

I think the best practice since C++14 is to avoid the argument passing weirdness altogether by handling the arguments yourself and always giving the INVOKE functions a zero-argument functor that encapsulates the arguments required by the actual target function. Doing it yourself allows you to get exactly the semantics you intend without having to know every quirk and workaround and the fine distinctions in the interfaces of the INVOKE family functions. C++14 generalized lambda capture makes it quite simple to encapsulate any kind of function and set of arguments.

In your case, this approach would result in:

```
#include <thread>

template <typename T>
struct f {
    void operator() (T& result) { result = 1;}
};

int main() {
    int x = 0;
    auto g = [](auto& result) { result = 1; };

    std::thread([&]{ return f<int>{}(x); });
    std::thread([&]{ return g(x); });
}
```

which performs exactly as intended and is more readable.

`std::reference_wrapper` was great in the TR1 days when we needed it to pass references through `std::bind`, but its glory days are past and I think it's best avoided in modern C++.

Comment: "Is more readable" is probably more a statement of opinion than fact. Given that I've been avoiding `std::bind` and `std::reference_wrapper` like the plague since C++11, my preference for lambdas biases my view of what is "readable."

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function to solve your problem.  It takes a function object, and returns a function object that will unpack `std::reference_wrapper`s before passing it on to the inner function object.

```
#include <utility>
#include <functional>

template<class T>
T&& unref( T&& t ){return std::forward<T>(t);}
template<class T>
T& unref( std::reference_wrapper<T> r ){ return r.get(); }

template<class F>
auto launder_refs( F&& f ) {
  return [f = std::forward<F>(f)](auto&&... args){
    return f( unref( std::forward<decltype(args)>(args) )... );
  };
}

//

  auto g = launder_refs([](auto& result) { result = 2; });
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/112bc744939edd03) -- now `g` behaves just like your original `g`, except when passed `std::reference_wrapper`s it turns them it to references before passing them to the `result` inside.

Your problem is that a `std::reference_wrapper<T>&&` passed to your lambda causes it to try to deduce a `U` such that `U&` = `std::reference_wrapper<T>&&`, and none exist.

In short, this is a limitation of type deduction in template functions (it does not consider conversions), as mixing both conversions and template type deduction in the same step would drive everyone batty.

The above code hides the `std::reference_wrapper`s from the underlying lambda closure (or function object).  It does so with minimal overhead as well.